# How do I perform volume rendering on image slices imported from a directory on my local machine?

Tags: legending, cluster-analysis, image3d

I have a set of image slices (in .MHA and DICOM formats) in a folder on my local machine. I will like to import these slices, perform rendering to get 3D volume, perform "ClusterComponents" on the rendered volume and then label each of the clusters as A1, A2, A3, A4, ........ or probably use legends.

1. Is this possible in Mathematica?
2. If yes, I would very glad to have your kind suggestions and opinions.
   Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `Import`ing the file and evaluating [`ClusteringComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html) on it? There is a 3D example in the documentation